# Libre Office presentation background with dark GTK theme

Tags: themes, libreoffice, gtk

I'm using a dark GTK theme. For some reason Libre Office Writer has a white background (like I want), but Impress does not. I do remember I had a white background in Impress as well some installations ago, so I think it should be possible to get this. I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm using Xubuntu with Xfce 4.10.
I just upgraded Libre Office to version 4, but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to turn off "Automatically detect high-contrast"?

> Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Accessibility > Automatically detect
>   high-contrast [off]

Comment: A lot has changed since I asked the question. Ubuntu dist-upgrades, LibreOffice updates, Xfce updates, a new gtk theme. Everything seems to work fine for me now. I can't test this, because the issue doesn't apply to me anymore. So I can't accept any answers.